# The ‘exit' statement in a shell script running in a Docker container exits the script but also the container; Can I prevent exiting the container?

Tags: linux, docker, shell

I want to run a Linux script in a Docker container and use the exit statement when I want to stop the script.
Unfortunately I also exit than the Docker container.
Is there a way to prevent exiting the container?

Here is the test code I’m using in its simplest form.

```
#!/bin/bash
function continue_exit {
        echo "Do you want step $1?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
           Yes ) break;;
           No ) exit;;
        esac
done
}

continue_exit "1"
echo "we continue"
```

Entering 1 runs the echo statement, entering 2 exits script AND container.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Gilles: I corrected and also saw that I had an older version with return instead of exit in there. Fixed it, but problem still remains.

Comment: If the main process exited, what would the container still be doing?

Comment: The container is still running and you can go back with: docker exec -it mykali /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your script.

The last character `“` (and another one) is not a simple double quote, but an unicode character:

```
$ echo '“' | od -c
0000000 342 200 234  \n
```

So replace it with `"` :

```
sed -i 's/“/"/g' script
```